# Hibernate does't update joined collection

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have an Employee entity (employee(id,name,company_id)):

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    private Company company;
    ...
}
```

and I have a Company entity (company(id,name)):

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id; 

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
    @Where(clause="status_code = '1'")
    private Set<Employee> employeeSet;
    ...
}
```

A company can have more employees, but one employee belongs to one company at a time. I joined them (I want to get the employees with status 1) and set cascade to all, but when I update an employee to be at another company then the employeeSet in the company doesn't refresh, nor the old neither the new company. This is the update method for the employee:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(employee);
```

I tried with update(employee) too, but no success. What do I miss from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `employeeSet` mapping is wrong. Change it to

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
@Where(clause="status_code = '1'")
private Set<Employee> employeeSet;
```

Second, you need to handle the other side of the relation as well, meaning you need to add the employee to the new company's `employeeSet` and remove it from the old one. This is necessary in order to maintain consistency of companies already loaded into hibernate session.

Comment: I corrected the mapping. The second part is harder than I thought. How can I know which company should be updated when I update an employee? Moreover I have company list with all companies, and have a Service list which contains companies taking services (it's a many-to-many connection), so the update should know about both. Does this mean I have to update manually all lists?

Comment: If I understood your model correctly, you need to update one company in case you are just removing the employee from it (that's `employee.getCompany()`) and another one if you are moving the employee to a new company (that's the new company). If there are several lists that hold the company that should be updated, it shouldn't be a problem as long as the lists contain managed entities, because they will all refer to the same company instance.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot it. Adding to the new company is working now, but how do I know the old company? I don't store the previous value anywhere.

Comment: You could use a query for it, just make sure you set `query.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)` because without it the changes will be flushed to database prior to executing the query.